# How to return property while object get undefined

Tags: google-apps-script

I got this error when trying to grab emails from Gmail inbox.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property "length" from undefined
```

I don't know if there is any other functions fit here better.

```
function getRelevantMessages()
{
  var threads = GmailApp.search("newer_than:30d AND label:payments",0,100);
  var messages=[];
  threads.forEach(function(thread)
                  {
                    messages.push(thread.getMessages()[0]);
                  });
  return messages;
}

function parseMessageData(messages)
{
  var records=[];
  for(var m=0;m<messages.length;m++)
  {
    var text = messages[m].getPlainBody();
// then regex and objects carry the returns
```

the code from pastebin https://pastebin.com/TRkEB6yM

Comment: If length is undefined, then it suggests that there are no messages, and possibly no threads. Time for some troubleshooting. Insert `Logger.log(threads.length)` after "var threads =..."; insert `Logger.log(messages.length)` before "return messages;" and tell us what they report.. FWIW, I have used `var messages = GmailApp.getMessagesForThreads(threads);` successfully - it would cut out several lines of your script.

Comment: is the parameter "messages" on your function parseMessageData(messages) coming from the function getRelevantMessages()?

Comment: I've tried logger.log(messages); return nothing
yes it comes from getRelevantMessages().

Comment: Well if you’re logger.log of messages was getting nothing that’s why you’re getting the error go figure out why you’re getting nothing

Comment: @cooper That's what im doing

Comment: @Johny Assuming you followed the code in the article in (https://blog.gsmart.in/), this is a webapp, but specific functions can be run from the Script editor. Open the Script editor, insert a new line immediately after `var threads = GmailApp.search(filter,0,10);`; enter `Logger.log("These are the threads: "+threads);` on the blank line; **save the file**;  then select Run, Run function, getRelevantMessages. Review the log (View, Logs) and tell us what is shown. Failing that, please tell what happens when you apply the filter directly in GMail.

Comment: @Tedinoz logger shows "GmailThread" repeated many times

Comment: Okay then try this: `threads.forEach(function(thread) {
  Logger.log("My Message: " + thread.getMessages()[0]);
  messages.push(thread.getMessages()[0]);
});
return messages;` What do you get?

Comment: This code works for me no problems: `function getRelevantMessages() {
  var threads = GmailApp.search("newer_than:30d",0,100);
  var messages=[];
  threads.forEach(function(thread) {
    messages.push(thread.getMessages()[0].getFrom());
  });
  Logger.log(messages);
  return messages;
}
`Try changing your filter.

Comment: [19-11-03 16:41:35:759 EAT] My Message: GmailMessage
five times. i got five messages when search with the same queries at Gmail homepage.

Comment: OK then provide us with the whole code so that we can see how you transferred data from one function to the other

Comment: whole code copy paste here https://pastebin.com/pqQ3hTFv

Answer (score 1):

Since the original question was getting `undefined` when searching for emails, MiMi, Cooper and Tedinoz solved it in the comments. Posting it as an answer for further searches.

```
function getRelevantMessages() { 

   var threads = GmailApp.search("newer_than:30d",0,100); 
   var messages=[];
   threads.forEach(function(thread) { 
       messages.push(thread.getMessages()[0].getFrom()); 
   }); 

  Logger.log(messages); 
  return messages; 

}
```